# Backbone jst.hamlc file not rendering <script> tag

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2, coffeescript, haml

Using backbone and jst.hamlc templates for an app. When the view is being created from the template, it outputs all normal data, but if a script tag is present the object, it chooses not to render.

The example content -

```
<script src='http://somescript.url'></script><br /><br />Some other stuff
```

jst.hamlc Template -

```
- if @page.attributes.content
  .text.page-content!= @page.attributes.content
```

rails `3.2.13`
haml_coffee_assets `1.12.0`

When I load the page, everything but the script renders. HTML tags except `<script>`.
Due to the fact that we're using a web service that requires a script tag to load content, we cannot pursue another route.

Any suggestions / solutions ?!?!

Thank you,
Seth

Comment: Can you use `%script(type="text/javascript" src="http://somescript.url")` or am I missing something in the question

Comment: No, it is being stripped out when haml compiles. I've tested it by grabbing the script src from the JSON output and adding it to a script tag  and that doesn't work. It seems that the script isn't either being parsed at all or firing at the wrong time.